# NGINX location block matching

Tags: nginx

I run a server on VestaCP, which auto formats nginx.conf and snginx.conf files when you create a web example. I have further modified these files. What I am doing is redirecting all urls to HTTPS. However, there are a couple of URLs that need to be on port 80, no SSL. I have configured one URL correctly, which is /prosphere

I need to make another configuration to keep a URL and ALL sub URLs on HTTP, and I cannot get NGINX to read it.

Here is my snginx.conf:

```
server {
listen      1.1.1.1:443;
server_name example.com www.example.com;
ssl         on;
ssl_certificate      /home/example/conf/web/ssl.example.com.pem;
ssl_certificate_key  /home/example/conf/web/ssl.example.com.key;
error_log  /var/log/httpd/examples/example.com.error.log error;


location = /prosphere {
    return 301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

location = ~*/football/sublimated-uniforms/sublimated-flag-football-jerseys/(.*)$ {
    return 301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

location = /football/sublimated-uniforms/prosphere-uniforms(?:/(.*))?$ {
    return 301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass      https://1.1.1.1:8443;
    location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|tif|tiff|css|js|htm|html|ttf|otf|webp|woff|txt|csv|rtf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx|odf|odp|ods|odt|pdf|psd|ai|eot$
        root           /home/example/web/example.com/public_html;
        access_log     /var/log/httpd/examples/example.com.log combined;
        access_log     /var/log/httpd/examples/example.com.bytes bytes;
        expires        max;
        try_files      $uri @fallback;
    }
}
```

And here is my nginx.conf

```
server {
listen      1.1.1.1:80;
server_name example.com www.example.com;
error_log  /var/log/httpd/examples/example.com.error.log error;

location / {
    proxy_pass      http://1.1.1.1:8080;
    location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|tif|tiff|css|js|htm|html|ttf|otf|webp|woff|txt|csv|rtf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx|odf|odp|ods|odt|pdf|psd|ai|eot$
        root           /home/example/web/example.com/public_html;
        access_log     /var/log/httpd/examples/example.com.log combined;
        access_log     /var/log/httpd/examples/example.com.bytes bytes;
        expires        max;
        try_files      $uri @fallback;
    }

    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

location = /prosphere {
    proxy_pass      http://1.1.1.1:8080;
}

location = /ps-config.html {
    proxy_pass      http://1.1.1.1:8080;
}

location = ~*/football/sublimated-uniforms/sublimated-flag-football-jerseys/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass      http://1.1.1.1:8080;
}

location = /football/sublimated-uniforms/prosphere-uniforms(?:/(.*))?$ {
    proxy_pass      http://1.1.1.1:8080;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I know I can combine these files, etc- but the server I am using likes them organized in this manner, and so do I. I know NGINX doesnt look at the order of location blocks, but rather first match- I cannot for the life of me get /football/sublimated-uniforms/sublimated-flag-football-jerseys/ to match anything. It needs to match the following:

/football/sublimated-uniforms/sublimated-flag-football-jerseys
/football/sublimated-uniforms/sublimated-flag-football-jerseys/
/football/sublimated-uniforms/sublimated-flag-football-jerseys/one
/football/sublimated-uniforms/sublimated-flag-football-jerseys/one/
/football/sublimated-uniforms/sublimated-flag-football-jerseys/one/two
/football/sublimated-uniforms/sublimated-flag-football-jerseys/one/two/

And any other variables.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `=` flag cannot be combined with regexp

Answer (score 0):

Well, that was silly. I needed to remove the = signs, a previous admin had put them in there and I was blind to even noticing them. I removed the = and added a ~* and all is working as intended. Thank you, Alexy Ten!